# How to get all Carousel data from Microsoft Bot Service?

Tags: botframework

I have an adaptive card carousel on the MS bot frameworks. Each adaptive card has multiple inputs.

There is a button 'submit' on the last adaptive card on the carousel. The button can only return the exact adaptive card data in JSON.

How can I get all the data of the carousel?